# How to get pass null values from your database column when data is filter and saved?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have few fields from the database column, table name has a list of fields to be saved. Some get saved, while others don't get saved, they appear as null (Dropdownlist for countries in the world, dietaryrequirements and StreetaddressLine). Have a look at the schema below from the database.

How do I get passed the null objects, this is my ASP.NET MVC web form. Need some help.

```
// Model

using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    namespace eNtsaRegistrationTraining.Models
    {
        public class eNtsaRegForm
        {
            [Key]
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string Position { get; set; }
            public string Company { get; set; }
            public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
            public string StreetAddressLine { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string StateProvince { get; set; }
            
            [Required]
            public int ZipCode { get; set; }
            public string Country { get; set; }
    
            [Required]
            public string Email { get; set; }
    
            [Required]
            public string CellNumber { get; set; }
            public string DietaryRequirements { get; set; }
    
    
        }
```

This is my controller action

```
    // Controller
     public ActionResult SubmitRegDetails(RegViewAndRoleViewModel eNtsaRegistration)
            {
               
    
                if(ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    eNtsaRegistration.RegForm.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                    db.eNtsaRegForms.Add(eNtsaRegistration.RegForm);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("SaveRegForm");
                }
                return View(eNtsaRegistration);
                
            }
```

And this is my data layer

```
    // DAL(Data-Access-Layer)
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using eNtsaRegistrationTraining.Models;
    
    namespace eNtsaRegistrationTraining.DAL
    {
        public class eNtsaRegistration:DbContext
        {
    
            public eNtsaRegistration() : base("eNtsaRegistration")
            {
            }  public DbSet<eNtsaRegForm> eNtsaRegForms { get; set; }
    
            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                Database.SetInitializer<eNtsaRegistration>(null);
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            }
        }
     }
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is a web framework, not an ORM or data access library. It looks like you're using Entity Framework. Which version?

Comment: Indeed, what's the question? How to pass missing choices from the view to the action? How to store those missing choices? (that's easy, set the relevant properties to `null` or whatever the appropriate "missing" value is)

Comment: Or are you asking why the values are null in the first place? Most likely because the dropdown/choice elements aren't bound to the DTO in the view. You haven't posted the view code though

Comment: @Panagiotis i am using entity framework, 4 version. Yes how to pass missing choise from the view to action. Please show me by some examples then can follow easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure  what framework you're using nor how you're populating the properties of the class instance that you're trying to save, but `StreetAddress`, `Country` and `DietaryRequirements` fields aren't marked as required in the code that you've given and so `NULL` is a valid value to store in the database.

I would first change that and then look at how you're populating those fields.

Comment: @ChrisDB i am using entity framework, on my model  as shown i am using data-anotation

Comment: @ChrisDB can u perhaps show me by pseudo code then i will follow as what to do exactly, i am struggling